# CURL badrequest 400 when submiting from webserver

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to submit a form to a .aspx page with curl and then do something with the response. The problem is that my code works when I'm submiting it from my local xampp server but when submited from webserver I get "HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid."
I tried removing CURLOPT_POST option, found it somewhere on SO. I also tried urlencoding but then I get nothing.

```
$url = "http://www.somepage.com/locations/default.aspx#location_page_map";
$kv[]='search=92627';
$kv[]='__VIEWSTATE';
$kv[]='__EVENTTARGET';
$query_string = join("&", $kv);
$ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $query_string);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT   5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($output);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_POST` should be a boolean, and you don't need to convert the `kv` array you can just pass the array in `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually leave out the `__VIEWSTATE` and `__EVENTTARGET` there most likely  something todo with ASP's form value persistence, also you can remove the `#location_page_map` as thats just to focus the page on the map section, so will not impact the results from the service/site your trying to scrape. You then use [http_build_query()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) to turn the array into a string for curl.

```
<?php 
//$url = "http://www.myfitfoods.com/locations/default.aspx#location_page_map";

$url = "http://www.somepage.com/locations/default.aspx#location_page_map";

$kv['search'] = '92627';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($kv));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($kv));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT   5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
$output = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($output);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: I'm still getting the error. But you were right about __VIEWSTATE and __EVENTTARGET parameters, it works without them on my local server. Have no idea what could cause it.

Comment: I cant help further unless I know the real url. you can remove it after letting me know ;p

Comment: well it's commented out in your answer, no idea how it got there. No secret :) http://www.myfitfoods.com/locations/default.aspx#location_page_map

Comment: oh right, yeah i google the rest of the url string just to test ;p if you used my example as-is unfortunately its hard to diagnose,  have you checked your host dont have a really old version of curl installed. Try without the #location_page_map in the url too, perhaps its that as its also not needed.

Comment: You googled it right :) Oh my God it works, it was the #location_page_map that was causing the problem. Do you have any idea why it worked on local server? You can edit your answer so I can mark it as accepted. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: not sure could be an old curl version, dont forget to accept if it helped, regards +1 yourself as its a generally good question.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't defined your `$kv` array propertly. Curl will take an array, but it has to be in `key=>value` format. All you've provided is 3 values. e.g. you'd actually be passing

```
=search%3D62627&=__VIEWSTATE&=__EVENTTARGET
^--no key       ^---no key   ^--- no key
```

Try:

```
$kv = array(
   'search' => 92627,
   'x' => '__VIEWSTATE',
   'y' => '__EVENTTARGET'
)
curl_setopt($ch, CURL_POSTFIELDS, $kv);
```

or similar instead.